# PL/SQL Update Trigger (Beginner)

Tags: sql, plsql

I have two tables. Table 1 includes a brief movie summary, Table 2 contains the entire movie bio.

I'd like to create an on update trigger that occurs when I update table 1. Essentially I want the first 30 characters to be updated in the table 1 movie summary, while the entire movie bio is updated in Table 2.

Any ideas to how I would begin this task?

Comment: Are the columns in both tables the same data type and maximum width?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with PL/SQL but I would try something like this:

```
Create Or Replace Trigger update_movie_bio
Before Update On Table1
For Each Row

Begin
    UPDATE Table2
    SET movie_bio = :new.movie_bio
    WHERE movie_id = :new.movie_id
End;
```

So then you would update Table 1 with the first 30 characters and then this would automatically fire and update Table 2.

To update Table 1 the query would look like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET movie_summary = SUBSTR("movie_summary", 0, 30)
WHERE movie_id = movie_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there anyway we can combine all of that into a single trigger by only updating table 1.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but I believe the above trigger is what you are after. The trigger fires automatically any time there is an update to Table1. So you store this trigger in with the database and let it be. Whenever Table1 is updated, this fires without you doing anything else. I just provided the Table 1 update query to show an example of what would fire the update_movie_bio trigger.

Comment: OK let me clarify, if the movie description is updated in Table 1, then the first 30 characters of the new description are updated in Table 1 and the ENTIRE description should be updated in Table 2.